# ApiController requires "/" at end of request

Tags: asp.net

I have a .Net Framework ApiController that works as long as I append "/" to the end of the request, but gives me a 404 without the "/".  To make it more compllicated, it will work without the "/" as long as there is no "." in the parameter.  Is there something I can do on my service to allow requests to work without "/"?

api/v1/users/sometext - this works

api/v1/users/some.text - this gives 404

api/v1/users/some.text/ - this works

```
public class UserApiController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/v1/users/{email}")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public object GetUserByEmail(string email)
```

Comment: Pretty sure you're going to need the trailing slash in any case. The only thing that I can think of is to encode the `.` as `%2E` and see if that lets you bypass the limitation.

Comment: Email addresses can contain several other even more conflicting characters, that will not work as a URL segment. My advice is to change both sides to use a query string parameter (and then use proper UrlEncoding). So `/v1/users?email=....`